# Animated doesn't work after setState is called

Tags: animation, react-native, setstate

#### Description

I want to perform some change before animation start, so I called setState() before Animated.spring().start(), I expected the component is updated first then animated, but the animation isn't started at all. Is this a bug? If not, how should I do?

#### Reproduction

Here's sample code:

```
this.setState({zIndexLeft: 0, zIndexRight: 1});
Animated.spring(this.state.contentPositionRight, {toValue: 200}).start((finished) => {
        this.setState({actionsheetState: -1})
});
```

#### Additional Information

- React Native version:0.42.3
- Platform: iOS
- Development Operating System: MacOS 10.12.4
- Dev tools:Xcode 8.3, iOS 10.3

Comment: Does the animation run if you comment out the first setState() call? It's hard to tell what could be happening without know what components are being affected by setState and Animated.spring. Remember that setState is asynchronous so there is no guarantee that it will be performed before Animated.spring begins/ends. If you can clear up the intent of your code, I can offer better suggestions.

Comment: @Michael Cheng Thanks for your proposal, I put the animation in the callback of setState, it works properly.

Comment: Alright, good to hear. Glad I could help.